# can I use an image that is on my computer with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, image, function, insert

I was trying to make a house that opens its door onmouseover.
I have already made the two images of the house on photoshop and saved them as .jpg

here's the code I made for HTML:

```
<img id="house" onmouseover="open()" src="doorclosed.jpg"/>
```

and here's the JavaScript code:

```
function open() {
            document.getElementById("house").src='dooropened.jpg';
    }
```

the problem is that when I click on the closed house image on the webpage I get a white page and the html file name is in the title bar.

what did I do wrong? shouldn't I add images from my computer? because I used same code with images from the internet using its url.

Comment: By default clicking on an image shouldn't trigger anything. You've also added your swapping code to `onmouseover`. Is there any other HTML on the page that might do something `onclick`?

Comment: @Halcyon sorry, my bad, I meant onmouseover.

Answer (score 0):

You must be change function name. For example change "open" to "changeImg".

```
<img id="house" onmouseover="changeImg()" src="doorclosed.jpg"/>

function changeImg(){
            document.getElementById("house").src='dooropened.jpg';
    }
```

Comment: thanks a lot that worked well, but how about onmouseout?

Comment: You shold be create new function for it . 
<img id="house" onmouseover="changeImg()" onmouseout=" resetImg()" src="doorclosed.jpg"/>
 <script>
 function changeImg(){     document.getElementById("house").src='dooropened.jpg'; 
} 













function resetImg () { document.getElementById("house").src='doorclosed.jpg'; } </script>

Comment: So the functions names **must** be like that? I thought I can name them whatever I want

Comment: You  must be followed the coding standard.
Function names SHOULD begin with the name of the module or theme declaring the function, so as to avoid name collisions.
Named functions MUST NOT have a space between the function name and the following left parenthesis.